# How to show custom button on custom objects?

Tags: salesforce

I have one custom object  Named Itnery and i created one custom button Named Save and in page layout under custom button section i drag the button there but it not shown in the Itnery  window when i opened it.Itnery section comes with Opportunity window.

Second thing is i want to save the data related to Itnery  like email,from,to etc on button click as i created and i did it as under:

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}

Itinerary obj= new Itinerary;

obj.Email_Content_*c = {!Itinerary*_c.Email_Content__c};
obj.Email_Subject_*c={!Itinerary*_c.Email_Subject__c};
obj.Email_To_*c={!Itinerary*_c.Email_To__c};
obj.Flight_Info_*c={!Itinerary*_c.Flight_Info_*c};
obj. Itinerary*_c={!Itinerary_*c.Itinerary*_c};
obj.Opportunity_*c={!Itinerary*_c.Opportunity__c};
Database.update(obj);
message ='Saved Successfully';
window.location.reload();

---

Behavior: execute javascript
Content Source " Onclick javascript

please let me knw if anythng wrong in the code also..as i am new to saleforce

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add your custom "Save" button to the related list.

Do it like this:
- at the Opportunity layout page click on "Edit layout" link
- then scroll down to related list (Itnery)
- click on the tool icon
- in the popup window you will see the settings of the related list
- there are "Columns" and "Buttons" areas, click on "Buttons"
- there are standard and custom buttons: select your custom button and click on the "Add" button
- save you settings